# How to assign reference instead of value in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

Take the following code for example,

```
var a = new StringBuffer("Foo!")
val b = a
a = null
println(b)
```

I expected the value of **b** to become **null**, but it didn't. Unlike Java, where references are assigned, here **a** was copied to **b**. How do we assign references in Scala instead of just copying values?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in Scala. And BTW it works exactly the same way as it does in Java:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer("Foo!");
    StringBuffer b = a;
    a = null;
    System.out.println(b);
    // Foo!
  }
}
```

And also Python, I might add, looking at your username:

```python
a = ['Foo!']
b = a
a = None
b
# >>> ['Foo!']
```

Comment: Wouldn't b be null in Java? In Java, the reference would be assigned, no? unless you do StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(a), in that case yes, it would be copied.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? It's just 4 lines of code.

Comment: I am totally confused now :(!. So, that means in Java, = at declaation, is just a short hand for a copy constructor?

Comment: This is how pretty much all major languages behave: C, Java, C♯, Python, Ruby, ECMAScript, PHP, you name it.

Comment: So, how do we assign references in Java? In C++, I can use pointers, how do we do that in Java?

Comment: There are no copy constructors in Java. And in fact, the only thing that is copied here is the pointer to the `StringBuffer`. The `StringBuffer` itself never gets copied in any of either your or my examples.

Comment: You can't. Just like in Scala or Python.

Comment: Got it. Basically, it just set the pointer of a to null, while b is still pointing to the original pointer, because if instead of doing a = null, I do a.append(" boo!"), Foo! boo! is printed. So, basically, in that case a and b are still pointing to the same object.

Comment: @pythonic Java doesn't have a copy constructor.  `a` and `b` are *references* not objects, otherwise `a = null` wouldn't make any sense. When you do `b = a` you copy the reference to the object.

Comment: @pythonic what you have to understand is that variables (of non-primitive types) are **references** themselves - a variable is not an object, it is a reference to an object. In Java and Scala there is not an explicit difference between variables that are object are variables that are references, like in C++. Setting one reference to `null` doesn't automatically set other variables that refer to the same object to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior in all sane languages. Think of that all variables and values were pointers, which in fact, under the hood, they are (with exception for primitive types).

This is just pseudocode, with c-like pointer semantics

```
StringBuffer* a = new StringBuffer("Foo!")
StringBuffer* b = a
a = null
println(b)
```

After all this, `b` still points to an object you created in the first line.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I just got confused :).

Comment: One more question, silly as it may sound, how will this get garbage collected in Java. In one of my code, I am having great problem with StringBuffer, as it seems that it never gets garbage collected, even if I do sb.setLength(0). Any idea, how to garbage collect it? And for example, if a put an element in an Array, and later set that element to null, would garbage collector know that it has to be garbage collected?

Comment: Basically it gets garbage collected when no variable has reference to it, for example if that variable gets out of scope, or is set to null. Regarding the array, answer is yes. Ofc there are exceptions to this and it can depend on how long the object survived or on kind of gc algorithm selected.

Comment: OK, lets say I have an Array a. And later I have val element = a[36]. And then I do element = null, would it get garbage collected, or would I also need to do a[36] = null, for it to get garbage collected?

Comment: You would need to set both to null. The array contains pointers as well. if you have `val element = a(36)`, there are two pointers for that object, one is `element`, and another is 36th element of array. If you set `element = null` and `a = null` it should work as well. Keep in mind that `element` must be a `var` not `val` so that you could reassign.

Comment: if you keep mutable state, you most commonly have a `var data: Vector[Data] = Vector()` and append new elements to it or remove them, not worrying about arrays and nulls that you shouldn't even see in scala.

Comment: @pythonic the garbage collector only runs when it needs to.  This improves efficiency but means that objects which could be collected might not be collected for some time or ever.